# Django logging to wxpython window?

Tags: django, wxpython

I'm writing a utility to start up a django server process that outputs its logs to a TextCtrl in a wxpython window. Unfortunately, a couple different approaches have led to weird issues where the operating system (OSX in this case) crashing the program with complaints about "Illegal Instruction" after a few successful log entries.

I'm currently doing this by implementing a logging.Handler subclass that posts events to wx that contain the logging records to be shown in the window. Is there a better approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wxPython requires it to be the main thread, so I am guessing that is the likely root cause of your issue. You have a couple of good approaches to try though.

First you could launch the Django server process as a thread from your wxPython program. Then you can use wxPython's thread-safe methods (`wx.CallAfter`, `wx.PostEvent`) to communicate with the UI.

Or you could just launch Django separately and log to a file. Then launch wxPython and have it basically tail the log file.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I ended up disabling the specialized Django logging, which directed the events to my wx logging handler. Making that execute `wx.CallAfter` fixed it all up!